# probability without replacement when numbers are drawn

Tags: probability

A jar contains ten marbles (marked from 1 to 10). Four marbles are drawn without replacement, the number noted. Find the probability of:
a.  Smallest number is 5?.
b.  Biggest number is 5?

Should I take favorable cases as 1 to 5 and then  to 10..how should I approach it.Please guide me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please read about the order statistics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Comment: How many ways are there to pick a sample of 4 numbers from 1 to 10 ? How many samples are there with numbers 1 - 5 out of which one is 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

so,you first draw a marble so what is the possibility that the number on it is 5-6(because we want more than 4).of course 2/6.so the probability of getting
more than 4 is 2/6.the second marble has the same probability.so the answer will be
(2/6)^4.